# np.mean return (nan) row values

Tags: python

This code is supposed to recalculate the (centroid), but the problem is that it sometimes returns (null) values, this problem started with large datasets, although it was working fine.

```
def Calc_New_cent(centroids, Data):
for m in range(k):
    for n in range(number_of_features):
        centroids.iloc[m, n] = np.mean(Data[Data['clusters'] == m + 1]['{}'.format(n + 1)])
return centroid
```

Comment: what are `k` and `number_of_features` ?? For what inputs does this function return null values? Also, please indent the code correctly. Please check [mcve]

Comment: `'{}'.format(n + 1)` is just `str(n+1)`

Answer (score 1):

If it works fine on small datasets, then the problem may are the large datasets themself. They often contain some invalid data. This can result into nan values. You should check the dataset.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).